Rust LibP2P transaction
I’m working on a project that I plan to make open-source in the future. It’s built using Rust and LibP2P to create an environment where smartphones can connect peer-to-peer to form a decentralized network of nodes
For about a week now, I’ve been stuck with a recurring issue in LibP2P: connections between nodes don’t stay open. I tried separating the roles of client and server to make debugging easier, but in the final project, every node will need to act as both a client and a server

The server starts correctly, listens on an address, and accepts connections.
The client discovers the server via mDNS, establishes a connection, exchanges a simple message
The connection closes immediately after, with this error: Error(Right(Closed))

My goal is to keep the connection open and enable continuous interactions between nodes.
Here are the main questions I have:

Why does my connection close immediately after being established?
Is this due to inactivity or event handling issues in LibP2P?
What’s the best way to implement persistent bidirectional communication between nodes?

If anyone has ideas or suggestions
https://github.com/EcoBlock-Network/EcoDAG.git
this is the link of my repo
i’d really appreciate the help. Thanks a lot!

Please include a [mre] directly in the question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
